# Search for a numeric range inside string in elastic search

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I wanted to search a numeric expression in elastic search.

Example

```
indent code 4.8663 spaces
indent code 121.232 spaces
indent code 12.3232 spaces
```

Example query

```
get all string with "indent code between 1 and 100"
```

It should get 1st and 3rd but not 2nd.

```
                    {
                        "span_near": {
                            "in_order": 1,
                            "clauses": [
                                {
                                    "span_term": {
                                        "request": "indent"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "span_term": {
                                        "request": "code"
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "span_multi": {
                                            "match":{
                                                "range": {
                                                    "request": {
                                                        "to": 100,
                                                        "from": 1
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "slop": 0,
                            "collect_payloads": 0
                        }
                    }
```

giving wrong result. as it is comparing using TermRangeQuery rather than NumericRangeQuery.

Comment: Is there a way for you to index a (possibly rounded) integer number (e.g. 5) instead of float values (e.g. 4.8663) or do you need that precision elsewhere?

Comment: precision is required in my scenario, but the above solution is not working even for rounded numbers

Comment: Please do let me know if any good solution is available for rounded number, it may help

Comment: I've added one solution for integer numbers below. It might help other people with the same issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can either replace float numbers by integer numbers (4.8663 => 5) or multiply your float numbers by a chosen power of 10 so that all numbers become integers (4.8663 => 48663), then you might be able to use the [`regexp` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) for this.

I've indexed three documents with integer numbers (5, 121 and 12) and I've been able to successfully retrieve the two in the 1-100 interval using the following query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "request": {
        "value": "<1-100>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you absolutely need to keep the precision for other reasons, then this might not work out for you.

Comment: Thanks but the regex may not be the best choice it is slow, and also for large ranges it does not work.

Comment: in range <6-9999999999> it is giving error as the range is two large, also for index like in my case which contain over thousand of items it is really slow for large range values.

Comment: Ok, let's figure out another solution then.